# Dynamic query for cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I need to write a Dynamic query for cursor to get the indexes names of the table.

## Attempt 1:

```
DECLARE @Cur AS Cursor

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL N'SET @Cur = CURSOR fast_forward for 
                        SELECT IndexColumn = i.name
                        FROM sys.indexes i
                        INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
                        WHERE
                        T.Name = ''' + @TableName + ''''
```

**Error**: Incorrect syntax near '+'.

## Attempt 2:

```
 DECLARE @sqlstatement nvarchar(max)

 SET @sqlstatement = 'DECLARE @Cur AS CURSOR fast_forward for 
                 SELECT IndexColumn = i.name
                 FROM sys.indexes i
                 INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
                 WHERE
                 T.Name = ''' + @TableName + ''''
 PRINT(@sqlstatement)
 EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstatement
```

**Error**: Incorrect syntax near 'fast_forward'.

Comment: The bigger question is, do you really need a cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor declaration is incorrect (lose the `@`/`AS`)

```
 SET @sqlstatement = 'DECLARE Cur CURSOR fast_forward for 
                 SELECT IndexColumn = i.name
                 FROM sys.indexes i
                 INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
                 WHERE
                 T.Name = ''' + @TableName + ''''
```

(Attempt 1 is incorrect as the cursor is not in scope of the batch built in the string)

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no need to declare like that as the cursor is not in scope. You can also do this -

```
SET @sqlstatement = 'DECLARE cur_mycursor CURSOR fast_forward for 
                 SELECT IndexColumn = i.name
                 FROM sys.indexes i
                 INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
                 WHERE
                 T.Name = ''' + @TableName + ''''
EXEC(@sqlstatement)

OPEN cur_mycursor

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_mycursor INTO .... blah..blah...
```